# Sum based on sub-sums

Tags: arithmetic

Let's say, we have three numbers: $a, b, c$

but we know only their sums: $x = a + b, y = b + c.$

> Is it possible to find sum $z = a + b + c$?

edit - $a, b, c$ are natural numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express a and c in term of b.
(i) a=x-b
(ii) c=-b+y.
Substitute in z,
z=(x-b)+b+(-b+y).
The natural number b determine the solution triplet (a,b,c). How many solutions b can we have? Any natural number smaller than min(x,y) will do.

Answer (score 1):

No.

For example, take $x=y=0$.

Then, taking an arbitrary value of $a$, you can set $b=-a$, $c=a$ and you will have $x=y=0$ and $z=a$.

Comment: thanks, you're right. But what if a, b, c are natural?

Comment: @user251405 Still no. Except in some special cases, like $x=y=0$, where clearly $a=b=c=0$.